# Refresh Chrome Extension without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reload

I am making a chrome extension, fetching Data from DB for particular language, but whenever I change language I have to refresh the chrome page to fetch the updated Data from DB.

Is there a way to fetch new Data as the language changes without refreshing the chrome page.

I tried using Mutation observer but failed. Kindly guide any way possible

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck